# How to get a list of sidebar fields programmatically?

Tags: api, metadata-api, sosl, search

Is there a way to programmatically determine which fields of an object are searched during sidebar search? Also, for custom objects, how does Salesforce decide which fields should be searched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce decides by this chart for all objects:

Specifically for custom objects:
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_fields_custom_object.htm&language=en_US

One way is to write a utility class that can give you the type of the field and decide by the chart if the fields are searchable or not

refrence: http://th3silverlining.com/2012/02/01/salesforce-dynamically-determining-the-field-type-of-a-dynamically-determined-sobject/

```
Schema.SObjectType t = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');

Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = t.getDescribe();
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = r.fields.getMap().get('name').getDescribe();

    system.debug(f.getType());
```

Comment: Oh, awesome help reference, this will come handy :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [SOSL reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm), especially the ["IN clause"](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_in.htm)

I know about:

- record's `Name`
- all fields of type Phone or Email
- all fields marked as External ID

Not sure about:

- fields marked as unique
- custom indexes (you can ask SF support to index a field for you)

The [Describe Field Results](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) methods should let you identify most of these properties and there's also a help topic: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004299. No idea what they mean by "SIDEBAR FIELDS"...